# How to get onChildClick value from expandablelistview in android?

Tags: android

I am working on a project with parsing JSON from url to ExpandableListView. Depending on the "status" tag value (active or pending) , will be placing records accordingly to to different groups "Active" and "Pending". Everything is working fine.

My Problem is when I click on a child inside the second group which should show different data, but I am getting data the data from first group child.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;

public class ExpandableActivity1 extends ExpandableListActivity {
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    JSONObject json_data = null;
    TextView txtMLSID;
        List<Map<String, String>> child1;
     List<Map<String, String>> child2;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);



    List<Map<String, String>> groups = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> group1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    group1.put("group", " Active");
    groups.add(group1);
    Map<String, String> group2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    group2.put("group", " Pending");
    groups.add(group2);
    child1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    child2 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();




    String url ="http://stage.realtylog.net/iPhone/functions.php?username=hussain16&act=listing";

    String  json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);




 try{




 jArray = new JSONArray(json);

 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length() ;i++){                       


     Map<String, String> childdata1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String status = e.getString("2");
         Log.e("log_tag","Status: "+status); 

         if (status.contains("active")){
             Log.e("log_tag","StatusActive: "+status); 

             childdata1.put("0",  String.valueOf(i+1)+" "+ e.getString("mlsid"));



                child1.add(childdata1); 

         }else if(status.contains("pending")){
             Log.e("log_tag","StatusPending: "+status); 



                Map<String, String> childdata2= new HashMap<String, String>();
                childdata2.put("0",  String.valueOf(i+1)+" "+ e.getString("mlsid"));


                child2.add(childdata2);




         }


    }   

  }catch(JSONException e)        {
 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
  }





       List<List<Map<String, String>>> childs = new ArrayList<List<Map<String,   String>>>();
        childs.add(child1);
        childs.add(child2);




    SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this, groups, R.layout.groups, new String[] { "group" },
            new int[] { R.id.group }, childs, R.layout.childs,
            new String[] { "0"}, new int[] { R.id.child });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

     @Override
    public boolean setSelectedChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
             boolean shouldExpandGroup) {
        //do something
       Log.e("log_tag","setSelectedChild: "); 
         return super.setSelectedChild(groupPosition, childPosition,
                  shouldExpandGroup);
   }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedGroup(int groupPosition) {
    //do something

       Log.e("log_tag","setSelectedGroup: "); 
        super.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition);
}


**//Here I am Getting problem**

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean onChildClick(
           ExpandableListView parent, 
           View v, 
           int groupPosition,
           int childPosition,
           long id) {
Log.d( "LOG_TAG", "onChildClick: "+"GROUP: "+groupPosition+"   CHILD Position:  "+ childPosition);

HashMap<String, String> o =    (HashMap<String, String>)  parent.getItemAtPosition(childPosition+1);           

              String val = o.get("0");
          Log.d( "LOG_TAG", "selected value :  "+val  );




           return false;

       }






 }
```

LogCat Info when   public boolean onChildClick () called :

```
10-20 11:24:28.004: DEBUG/LOG_TAG(1652): onChildClick: GROUP: 0   CHILD Position:  0
10-20 11:24:28.004: DEBUG/LOG_TAG(1652): selected value :  1 555
10-20 11:24:42.454: DEBUG/LOG_TAG(1652): onChildClick: GROUP: 1   CHILD Position:  0
10-20 11:24:42.454: DEBUG/LOG_TAG(1652): selected value :  1 555
```

Logcat shows that I am getting same value for group1(Active) and group2(Pending)

I need specific value for each child view based on click.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use Adapter's `getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)` method to retrieve the instance of child and the cast it to your Map and get it working.

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(this, (String)((Map<String, String>)
                adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get("lalit"),
                                                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onChildClick(parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to access the global adapter instance. Instead use the provided method for getting the adapter called getExpandableListAdapter().

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    System.out.println(" ----- " + type);
    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
        int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);
        Toast.makeText(this,title + ": Child " + childPos + " clicked in group "+ groupPos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
        Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Group " + groupPos + " clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I did in my application

Comment: @NagkeeranPiraba:this method is not called when i click on child item, Can u explain me a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

The below isn't perfect but it works. It might be helpful to those who need to access the view without overriding the onChildClick method such as a custom dialog with an ExpandableListView.

```
    ExpandableListView ellQuickKeys = (ExpandableListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ellQuickKeys);

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
            new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                            this,
                            createGroupList(),                              // Creating group List.
                            R.layout.group_row,                             // Group item layout XML.                       
                            new String[] { "Group Item" },  // the key of group item.
                            new int[] { R.id.row_name },    // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.                                   
                            createChildList(),                              // childData describes second-level entries.
                            R.layout.child_row,                             // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                            new String[] {"Sub Item"},              // Keys in childData maps to display.
                            new int[] { R.id.lblChildText}             // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
                    );

    ellQuickKeys.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {    
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
            Log.d("Selected text: " + ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblChildText)).getText());

            return false;
        }
    });
    ellQuickKeys.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
```

child_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@+id/lblChildText"
     android:paddingLeft="50dp"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:textSize="18dp"
     android:textStyle="normal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```